# WPF Canvas Scaling/Transform to Fit

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, scaletransform

I'm reposting this question as I didn't get much of a response last time, hopefully a bit of re-wording might help...

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to create a databound canvas, that will automatically scale its contents to 'fill' up the available space. Sort of like a zoom to fit operation. Unfortunately my WPF skills aren't yet very strong, and I'm struggling to work out how to do this last part. I've followed some databinding examples to get the canvas bound, but not sure if maybe its wrong and hindering me.

I've got two basic problems at the moment depending on the way I try and tackle the solution, either:

- I don't know how to make the
  canvas re-scale automatically
  through XAML if its possible using a
  transform.
- I can't seem to
  reference the canvas in the behind
  code, I'm guessing because its part
  of an ItemsControl?

An example of what I'm trying to achieve, I've got A I want to try and get B:

(*removed expired link to an img*)

The code I'm currently using is pretty simple, just creating 4 dots with a given co-ordinate, and a another view model to wrap these up in.

```
public class PointCollectionViewModel
{
    private List<PointViewModel> viewModels;
    public PointCollectionViewModel()
    {
        this.viewModels = new List<PointViewModel>();
        this.viewModels.Add(new PointViewModel(new Point(1, 1)));
        this.viewModels.Add(new PointViewModel(new Point(9, 9)));
        this.viewModels.Add(new PointViewModel(new Point(1, 9)));
        this.viewModels.Add(new PointViewModel(new Point(9, 1)));
    }

    public List<PointViewModel> Models
    {
        get { return this.viewModels; }
    }
}

public class PointViewModel
{
   private Point point;
   public PointViewModel(Point point)
   {
       this.point = point;
   }

   public Double X { get { return point.X; } }
   public Double Y { get { return point.Y; } }
}
```

Then the PointCollectionViewModel is used as the DataContent for my AutoResizingCanvas, which has the following XAML to implement the binding:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfCanvasTransform.AutoResizingCanvas"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCanvasTransform"
    x:Name="parent">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Models}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="DarkSeaGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
            </Canvas.LayoutTransform>

        </Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PointViewModel}">
        <Ellipse Width="3" Height="3" Fill="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}"/>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As your `Canvas` doesn't seem to have fixed width and height, I would include it into a `Viewbox`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="DarkSeaGreen">
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" />
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Alternatively, place your entire `UserControl` into a `ViewBox`.

Comment: @Mart : Very interesting, it looks like it is close to what I want. If I change my code like you suggested I get an InvalidOperationException "VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate must contain a Panel. 'System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox' is not a Panel."

Comment: @Mart : If I wrap my AutoResizingCanvas UserControl in the viewbox as per your other suggestion my points do scale, however they appear in a strange location and I loose my background colour. See screenshot : http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/4481/imagejc.jpg

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that the Canvas has no dimension. Its parent container makes it take the whole available space.
If you know bounds to your points' X and Y, set them to Canvas Width and Height. This way putting a Viewbox around the UserControl or ItemsControl will actually stretch it.

Comment: I added a new method to go through all my items in my ViewModel to work out the extreme values. Once I'd done that I had to go through them all again, and adjust the points to shift the whole dataset to (0,0) rather than starting at (1,1). Currently trying to look at using a TranslateTransform to try and do this.

Comment: Your PointViewModel class can be used for the translation. This is what ViewModels are used for: convert your actual data into view data. Change your X and Y getters to decrease the value by one.

Comment: @Ian I know this is a very old question, but how did you get around the InvalidOperationException "VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate must contain a Panel. 'System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox' is not a Panel." I am currently trying to do exactly the same thing....

Comment: @packoman I'll be honest I don't know and haven't used WPF since dabbling several years ago. Could you try putting a panel in the template?

Comment: Solution does not work. As said before, ViewBox can not be as the root of ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: Came here from Google `Alternatively place your entire UserControl into a ViewBox` only thing that worked for me.